# Castle Windsor WCF interceptors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, castle-windsor, aop

I am having a hard time getting interceptors to work in a MVC application that is hosting WCF services.

I want to add fine grained control over AOP using classes/methods decorated with attributes, but the interceptor is never called using the WCF facility.

In `Global.asax` I have:

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new RequireAspects());
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

`RequireAspects` wires up the interceptors:

```
public class RequireAspects : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    if (Attribute.IsDefined(model.Implementation, typeof(CacheAttribute)))
    {
        model.Interceptors.Add(InterceptorReference.ForType(typeof(Caching)));
    }
}
```

Interceptor looks like so:

```
public class CacheAttribute : Attribute { };

public class Caching : IInterceptor
{
 ...
}
```

Service:

```
[Cache]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    ...
}
```

And finally services are installed:

```
public class ServicesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, 
    Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
               .InNamespace("Test.Services")
               .Configure((c => c.LifestyleTransient())));
    }
}
```

Services configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Test.Services.TestService">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="Test.Services.ITestService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
       </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The interceptor is clearly added and a proxy is created, but the interceptor is never called.

I have reviewed this working example of interceptors with WCF, but doesn't meet my use case.
https://github.com/RussellPolitzky/Castle-Windsor-WCF-Service-With-Interceptor-and-Meta-Data-Publishing

The code above works for all other cases in which I use AOP in MVC and libraries.

Comment: Please show either .svc file or code instantiating your service.

Comment: Sorry.  It is using the Default Factory.  <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Services.TestService"
    CodeBehind="TestService.svc.cs" Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service method (not shown) is probably not declared as virtual. Interceptors can only work when resolving for an interface or for virtual members on a class.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll have to try that.  Not sure how the Facility works to resolve references.  As you can see there is ITestService, but if it is not resolving from that then it is a definite possibility.  I will check in the morning.

Comment: The default behaviour is to resolve using the component name (Test.Services.TestService) which means it will be returning a class (not interface) and therefore 'virtual' is required.